# Problem arising from quantisation of e.m. field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematics, notation, conventions

In my studies on the quantisation of the electromagnetic field I've come across a small calculation that I wasn't able to reproduce. Remember the following:

In the Gupta-Bleuler method to quantize the e.m. field the Lagrangian is given by the following quantity:

$\mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu} A^{\mu})^2$ where $F^{\mu \nu} = \partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - \partial^{\nu} \partial^{\mu}$. It is possible to rewrite the first term as $\mathcal{L_{max}} = -\frac{1}{2}[\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}]F^{\mu \nu}$

In the calculation I'm trying to follow upon constructing the Hamilton density from this Lagrangian the following step made:

$-\mathcal{L} = + (\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu})(\partial^{\nu} A^{\mu})$

I was able to show that this holds true by writing out all the parts of the sum, but I wasn't able to do it while keeping with the Einstein sum convention.

$-\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}([\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}](\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - \partial^{\nu} \partial^{\mu}) + (\partial_{\mu} A^{\mu})^2) = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu} - \partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial^{\nu} \partial^{\mu} + (\partial_{\mu} A^{\mu})(\partial_{\nu} A^{\nu}))$ at which point I don't have an idea how to continue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you were able to show it, then what is the question? You want someone else to show it again?

Comment: It took me like 1 hour to write out all the addends and look what cancels out and what not but I bet someone who's proficient at the Einstein convention could do it in half a minute without going through all of this work. 
Edit: also, I might've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there should be a mistake.
Let $A^{\mu}(x)=\partial^{\mu} \theta (x)$. Clearly you have $F^{\mu \nu}=0$. Thus, you just have to find a function $\theta(x)$ such that:
$$(\partial_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \theta)(\partial^{\nu} \partial^{\mu} \theta)\neq \frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\nu} \partial^{\nu} \theta)(\partial_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \theta). $$
Just use a function $\theta(t,x,y,z)=g(t)$. As a result, the left side of the equation becomes:
$$(\partial_{\nu} \partial_{\mu} g(t))(\partial^{\nu} \partial^{\mu} g(t))=(\partial_{0} \partial_{0} g(t))(\partial^{0} \partial^{0} g(t))=\left(\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial t}^2} g(t)\right)^2,$$
while the right side becomes:
$$\frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\nu} \partial^{\nu} g(t))(\partial_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} g(t))=\frac{1}{2} (\partial_{0} \partial^{0} g(t))(\partial_{0} \partial^{0} g(t))=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{{\partial t}^2} g(t)\right)^2.$$